# How do I get Access subreport to display all items in a group?

Tags: ms-access, subreport

I am creating a pricelist in Access report. I have (grouped by product type) description, unit of measure, Price, NoteIndex columns. I am trying to create a subreport in the footer of a grouping by product type to list the note index with the corresponding note.

Source data

```
Product Type    Description     UOM    Price    NoteIndex   Note  
Fruit           Apple           Each    1       N1          Red  
Fruit           Banana          Each    1.25    N2          Yellow and Red  
Vegetable       Peppers         LB      0.25    N2          Yellow and Red  
Vegetable       Beans           LB      0.55
```

Desired Result:

```
Description     UOM    Price    NoteIndex  
Apple           Each    1       N1  
Banana          Each    1.25    N2

NoteIndex for Fruit         
N1  Red     
N2  Yellow and Red
```

Currently I have only been able to display the 1st result and that is it. How can I get all of them to display for the group?

Comment: Show the subreport RecordSource query. What are the Master/Child linking fields? I have no problem creating the desired result.

Comment: Why does Note data need to be in subreport and not just with each record?

Comment: The notes can be lengthy and many of the items in the main report have the same note. It saves space and is easier to read if the notes are in a subreport rather than in the grid being created in the main report grouping. But I also need the notes under the each grouping rather than at the end of the entire report.  I am able to do this in Excel but Excel is terrible at page break detection and I spend a lot of time cleaning up the formatting.